# .Net Core 1.1 with ADAL: The dependency NetStandard.Library >= 1.6.0 could not be resolved

Tags: .net-core, adal

I'm trying to use ActiveDirectory client on my `NetCore 1.1` project. Project restores fine, but doesn't build. When building I get an error `The dependency NetStandard.Library >= 1.6.0 could not be resolved` that points to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Why can't this dependency be satisfied? Library used to work before upgrading from `NetCore 1.0.1`

Here is my project.json (which contains lot's of extra stuff trying to resolve the problem):

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.7",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }

  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win8-x64": {},
    "win7-x64": {}
  },
  "frameworks": {

    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1",

      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }

  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this issue too. It seems that this package is not deploy properly to Nuget.

The issue could be fixed when I comment the line below in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.nuspec file:

```
<!--<dependency id="NetStandard.Library" version="1.6.0" />-->
```

However, I still get the exception when use this version package. I also am trying to submit this issue.

As a workaround, you can downgrade this package to version 3.13.6 which works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently changing the casing of the name for "NetStandard" in the nuspec file to "NETStandard" can fix it as well.

> "ADAL 3.13.7 requires "NetStandard" library and in the applications
> common import, the application reuiqres NETStandard, i.e. a casing
> issue."
>
> So the fix here is to update the adal's nuspec with correct casing i.e. NETStandard.

See discussion here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/559#issuecomment-261768339