# Visual Studio dot net core project reference error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

When, I'm creating new .net core project, from any of this templates: [image]

It get this reference error:
[image]

And this errors in code:
[image]

`dotnet restore` output:
[image]

*P.S.: here is my [Visual Studio info](http://pastebin.com/Ps4rz4eW)*

Comment: can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764658/net-core-1-1-with-adal-the-dependency-netstandard-library-1-6-0-could-not-b and see if it fixes your problem?

Comment: Mate I've found a topic see if this helps you out? http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2016/07/26/what-should-you-know-about-net-core.aspx i think it explains everything with pictures and test and etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [topic](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2016/07/26/what-should-you-know-about-net-core.aspx) I changed dependencies in `project.json` manually:

from

[image]

to

[image]

And now all works fine:

[image][image]

Comment: @Valkyriee, thanks alot. The problem was simple, but your comment greatly helped